# Navigation Architecture Component with master/detail view

Tags: android, android-architecture-components

Is there a way, when using Navigation Architecture Component (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/), to have multiple fragments shown in an activity at same time (e.g. for a master/detail tablet type UI)?